# How to subclass AbstractUser in Django?

Tags: django

I'm trying to extent my user model. In the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) for extending the user model it says:

> ... just want to add some additional profile information, you could simply subclass django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser

I don't have experience in subclassing models. I've set everything up except for subclassing the model to `AbstractUser` and can't seem to find good documentation on it. Does anyone have experience subclassing `AbstractUser`?

My `models.py`:

```
class AuthKey(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
authkey = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

My `admin.py`:

```
class AuthKeyInline(admin.StackedInline):
model = AuthKey
can_delete = False
verbose_name_plural = 'AuthKey'

# Defines a new User admin
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (AuthKeyInline, )

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: did `AuthenticationKey` is `AuthKey` ?

Comment: Yeah. That’s a small error I’ll edit but question of subclassing still stands

Comment: You have a perfectly good AuthKey model which has a one-to-one relationship with User. Why do you think you need this to subclass AbstractUser?

Comment: I want to subclass so I can refer to it in my views. Request.user.authkey isn’t valid b.c it’s not part of the user model currently. Subclassing would allow me to refer to it in views... unless I’m missing something.

Comment: Those two things are not in any way related. If you want to access it in your view, do `request.user.authkey.authkey`.